# Ec2 Rabbitmq migration to amazonmq

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

My company is trying to migrate rabbitmq in ec2 to amazon mq rabbitmq brokers. What would be the process to do the migration? In ec2 rabbitmq all queues and exchanges are on the 3 ec2 instances but we need to split the queues into each application team microservices and put it in on the amazon mq raabitmq brokers? Any idea how to proceed this migration?

Need solution for the migration